# How to set active element in custom control Angular?

Tags: angular

I have implemented `ControlValueAccessor` interface in my custom component:

I wonder how to set `active` class for selected element?

I have tried:

```
  <span
        [ngClass]="{ 'primary-color-dark': option.key == value }"
        *ngFor="let option of options"
        (click)="optionSelect(option)"
        class="badge p-2 badge-unchecked mb-1 mr-2"
        >{{ option.value }}</span
    >
```

Is there method `currentValue` in `ControlValueAccessor`?

Comment: How do you mean? I tried to find option from loop in `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: I guess `ControlValueAccessor` should have selectedModel

Comment: Also how o listen updated model?